# Distributing Apples and oranges. confused about solution

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

How many ways are there to distribute 4 identical oranges and 6 distinct apples into 5 distinct boxes

I know you find number of ways for apples which is 5^6.

The solution tells me that the ways for oranges is 8 choose 4.

You then multiply both of them together to get solution, which is 1,093,750

My question is....where does 8 come from, for 8 choose 4???

Comment: Yeah, that looks like a typo.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the technique of [Stars and Bars, also known as using identical dividers](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/Ball-and-urn).

In this case, we use 4 dividers to simulate distributing the oranges amongst 5 boxes.